# Unable to hit .html page with Selenium?

Tags: php, html, selenium, behat, mink

I am using behat/mink, selenium 2 driver, chrome driver in php.
I am having trouble getting to a dummy html page. We have a site and we are adding a chat bot to the landing page, the chat bot is an iframe that gets loaded onto the bottom of the page. I want to say, we did was because we had a third party team using heroku that deved this and I thought it was probably a redirect issue but they couldn't figure it out so we spun up this little dummy page to see if it would help.
We spin up a dummy .html page and put the chatbot in so I can build automation around it. Well, I am getting 404 error when it tries to find the page. The thing is, I can get to it either manually or by using postman no problem. I am at a loss as I have never seen this before, the only thing I can think of is maybe because it's an HTML page with no-js? Any help is appreciated!

As stated above we have tried to spin up a dummy site (as well as another to see if it was caching).

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this, the issue was the index.html not being populated.

Comment: Remember that if the post was based on something that cannot be reproduced, and the solution was "I/we forgot to do something", that's a post worth deleting again.